# Jenkins pipeline CleanWs() - pattern delete

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Currently working on jenkins pipelines and on a particular case I need to clean only files with given extension (most of the times they are in one, particular folder).

**Directory structure:**
`${WORKSPACE}/some_folders/folder_to_clean`

I have tried:

```
cleanWs deleteDirs: true, notFailBuild: true,
                patterns: [
                [pattern: '*.png', type: 'INCLUDE'],
                [pattern: '*.log', type: 'INCLUDE'],
                [pattern: '*.lock', type: 'INCLUDE'],
                [pattern: 'Result_*.tsv', type: 'INCLUDE'],
                [pattern: 'report.html', type: 'INCLUDE']
                ]
```

but it does not work, no files are deleted. Then I tried to clean with specific directory in pattern:

```
cleanWs deleteDirs: true, notFailBuild: true,
                patterns: [
                [pattern: '${WORKSPACE}/some_folders/folder_to_clean/*.png', type: 'INCLUDE'],
                [pattern: '${WORKSPACE}/some_folders/folder_to_clean/*.log', type: 'INCLUDE'],
                [pattern: '${WORKSPACE}/some_folders/folder_to_clean/*.lock', type: 'INCLUDE'],
                [pattern: '${WORKSPACE}/some_folders/folder_to_clean/Result_*.tsv', type: 'INCLUDE'],
                [pattern: '${WORKSPACE}/some_folders/folder_to_clean/report.html', type: 'INCLUDE']
                ]
```

but it also doesn't work. Is there any way to do it with `cleanWs()` or should I try different approach? (I know, that `cleanWs()` should be used to clean the cuurent workspace and it is good practice to do so, but in this case it needs to stay on the node)

Comment: it seems like your pattern is incorrect. You may have to use a different pattern "\*\*/*.png"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Workspace Cleanup plugin documentation](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ws-cleanup/#plugin-content-configuration), use [ant Directory scanner](https://ant.apache.org/manual/api/org/apache/tools/ant/DirectoryScanner.html) patterns. Also see [ant PatternSet](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/patternset.html) manual page for examples.

That means you need to match the directory part as well, using "**", ie: `**/*.ext`.

You could also remove an entire directory, as opposed to the contents only.

Comment: I will try it, unfortunately I have to delete only some contents, not the directory itself